# Limit of Cauchy sequence of rationals

Tags: analysis

To prove that, if $(x_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence of rationals defining x, then $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k=x$, my textbook (*The way of Analysis*)states the following.

Given the error $\frac{1}{n}$, we can find $m$ such that $j,k \geq m$ , $|x_j-x_k|<\frac{1}{n}$. But then $j\geq m$ implies $|x_j-x|<\frac{1}{n}$, since this follows from  $|x_j-x_k|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $k$ large, which is what we have for $k\geq m$.

I don't quite understand the part after "But then $j\geq m$ also implies...". Could someone explain how it holds? Thanks in advance! Also, is it a typo that the textbook actually wanna say "But then $k \geq m$ also implies ..."? If so, can someone explain how one can replace $x_k$ with $x$ in the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Because if $k,j\geq m$, $$|x_j-x_k|<\frac{1}{n},$$
and thus $$|x-x_j|=\lim_{k\to \infty }|x_j-x_k|<\frac{1}{n}.$$